# connect to putty, using same session login to 2nd linux server via python

Tags: python, putty

Is there a way to:

1. open putty/plink session and login to linux server via python

2. in current session login to another linux server via python 

3. leave putty session open and available for user to run other commands manually?

Notes: 

- Script needs to run on Windows machine accessing linux server via putty.

- 1 was easy with subprocess.Popen(). 

- I'm stuck with sending password for next server login. RSA ssh keys are restricted on our servers.

Any ideas? May be other alternative to python script?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding you want to go from a Windows machine to Linux Server A, and then from that SSH session, connect from Linux Server A to Linux Server B?

Comment: absolutely right. Well, I gave it another thought, so it can be same thing but from linux machine 0(to machine A and from there to machine B)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Use `pexpect`.

But I must note that you can't use pexpect on windows without installing cygwin. When you want run your program directly on windows without cygwin, you want use `winexpect` (https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home).

Pexpect/Winexpect usage [example](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/346/python-how-to-access-ssh-with-pexpect/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect

ssh_newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
# my ssh command line
p=pexpect.spawn('ssh mysurface@192.168.1.105 uname -a')

i=p.expect([ssh_newkey,'password:',pexpect.EOF])
if i==0:
    print "I say yes"
    p.sendline('yes')
    i=p.expect([ssh_newkey,'password:',pexpect.EOF])
if i==1:
    print "I give password",
    p.sendline("mypassword")
    p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
elif i==2:
    print "I either got key or connection timeout"
    pass
print p.before # print out the result
```

In your case you must use `plink` instead of `ssh` and `winexpect` instead of `pexpect`.

Comment: thanks a lot Igor, that is useful module to use. It worked to ssh and do any commands. even overtake the session by p.interact().
The moment where I'm stuck with it is entering a second password. This might be a dumb issue, but I can't see the reason. 
So for example(made it as simple as possible):

Comment: `p=pexpect.spawn('ssh mysurface@192.168.1.105')`

Comment: everything is good. So now I want to copy a file from another machine that will require password:

Comment: `p.sendline('scp mysurface@10.10.10.10:/home/file /tmp')`

Comment: It does find "password" with expect, but doesn't insert password.
Weird, because it inserts password with no problem for the first time while ssh-ing